# bert model showing TypeError: Layer input_spec must be an instance of InputSpec. Got: InputSpec(shape=(None, 55, 768), ndim=3)

Tags: python, keras, android-intent, classification, bert-language-model

I am trying to use bert pretrained model for intent classification. here is my code in jupyter notebok.

```
class DataPreparation:
    
    text_column = "text"
    label_column = "intent"

    def __init__(self, train, test, tokenizer: FullTokenizer, classes, max_seq_len=192):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_seq_len = 0
        self.classes = classes

        ((self.train_x, self.train_y), (self.test_x, self.test_y)) = map(self.prepare_data, [train, test])

        print("max seq_len", self.max_seq_len)
        self.max_seq_len = min(self.max_seq_len, max_seq_len)
        self.train_x, self.test_x = map(self.data_padding, [self.train_x, self.test_x])

    def prepare_data(self, df):
        x, y = [], []

        for _, row in tqdm(df.iterrows()):
            text, label = row[DataPreparation.text_column], row[DataPreparation.label_column]
            tokens = self.tokenizer.tokenize(text)
            tokens = ["[CLS]"] + tokens + ["[SEP]"]
            token_ids = self.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)
            self.max_seq_len = max(self.max_seq_len, len(token_ids))
            x.append(token_ids)
            y.append(self.classes.index(label))

        return np.array(x), np.array(y)

    def data_padding(self, ids):
        x = []
        for input_ids in ids:
            input_ids = input_ids[:min(len(input_ids), self.max_seq_len - 2)]
            input_ids = input_ids + [0] * (self.max_seq_len - len(input_ids))
            x.append(np.array(input_ids))
        return np.array(x)

tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file=os.path.join(bert_ckpt_dir, "vocab.txt"))

def model_defination(max_seq_len, bert_ckpt_file):
    
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(bert_config_file, "r") as reader:
        bc = StockBertConfig.from_json_string(reader.read())
        bert_params = map_stock_config_to_params(bc)
        bert_params.adapter_size = None
        bert = BertModelLayer.from_params(bert_params, name="bert")
        
    input_ids = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_len, ), dtype='int32',name="input_ids")
    bert_output = bert(input_ids)

    print("bert shape", bert_output.shape)

    cls_out = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda seq: seq[:, 0, :])(bert_output)
    cls_out = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(cls_out)
    logits = keras.layers.Dense(units=768, activation="tanh")(cls_out)
    logits = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(logits)
    logits = keras.layers.Dense(units=len(classes), activation="softmax")(logits)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_ids, outputs=logits)
    model.build(input_shape=(None, max_seq_len))

    load_stock_weights(bert, bert_ckpt_file)

    return model

classes = train.intent.unique().tolist()

data = DataPreparation(train, test, tokenizer, classes, max_seq_len=128)

data.train_x.shape

data.train_y[0]

model = model_defination(data.max_seq_len, bert_ckpt_file)
```

Now when I am trying to call the function, I am getting error. The parameter values have max_seq_len = 55, bert_ckpt_file = bert checkpoint file.

when i create the model i am getting the below error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-af3e534b3882> in <module>
----> 1 model = model_defination(data.max_seq_len, bert_ckpt_file)

<ipython-input-16-a83a622dafe3> in model_defination(max_seq_len, bert_ckpt_file)
      9     input_ids = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_len, ), dtype='int32',name="input_ids")
     10     #input_spec = tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(ndim=3)
---> 11     bert_output = bert(input_ids)
     12 
     13     print("bert shape", bert_output.shape)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    974     # >> model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    975     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
--> 976       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
    977                                                 input_list)
    978 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1112         layer=self, inputs=inputs, build_graph=True, training=training_value):
   1113       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
-> 1114       outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
   1115           inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1116 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    846       return tf.nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    847     else:
--> 848       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    849 
    850   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    886           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    887           inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
--> 888           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    889 
    890         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    693       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    694         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 695           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    696         else:
    697           raise

TypeError: in user code:

    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bert\model.py:80 call  *
        output           = self.encoders_layer(embedding_output, mask=mask, training=training)
    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1030 __call__  **
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py:2659 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bert\transformer.py:209 build
        self.input_spec = keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=input_shape)
    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py:2777 __setattr__
        super(tf.__internal__.tracking.AutoTrackable, self).__setattr__(name, value)  # pylint: disable=bad-super-call
    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:530 _method_wrapper
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\kamrul.moin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1296 input_spec
        raise TypeError('Layer input_spec must be an instance of InputSpec. '

    TypeError: Layer input_spec must be an instance of InputSpec. Got: InputSpec(shape=(None, 55, 768), ndim=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the error. It was due to the shape of my training data. I added index as  a column in the training data. After reset the index column in the training data i get it right.
The below code solved the error:

```
train = train.reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.reset_index(drop=True)
```